# Prevent images from scaling up more that original size

Tags: typo3

Images which are rendered by TYPO3 graphics functions, are scaled up more than 100% of there original size, actually.

Are there any ways to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah that is possible to configure. Therefore two configuration options are responsible/available:

1) **TypoScript Setup**: (works only in older TYPO3 versions =< v7.6/v8.2)

```
config.noScaleUp = 1
```

2) **In your Configuration** *LocalConfiguration.php/AdditionalConfiguration.php*:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['processor_allowUpscaling'] = false;
```

These are the possible options to configure it for your TYPO3 instance.

Of course, you can additionally set (maximum) widths/heights directly where you configure the processing of your image (Fluid image view helper or TypoScript options - depending on your integration).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!

Comment: At time of writing my answer (October 2016), I figured out, that the first possibility (through TypoScript) is broken in TYPO3 8.4.0-dev. I've already found the cause and created an issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/78134. Just in case if your TypoScript setting isn't working.