# image alignment in typo3 not work properly, why

Tags: typo3

The movie explains everything,

[Youtube-Video-link-kurwa-mać!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U69FS_OH5lY)

Even the most basic thing - image width settings - does not work in Typo 3. How to fix it?

Can't typo3 programmers do even something as simple as aligning images well?

Answer (score 0):

There are several concepts dealing with those images which might or might not relate to the sitepackage or another extension you are using to get your content to the frontend.

So most of the stuff is actually not related to TYPO3, since it's a problem of the CSS to properly deal with repsonsive images, but some of the things shown in the video are correct:

1. There is a maximum width for images in the default elements, that applies to pure image elements as well as to text/media elements, which is configurable in TypoScript
2. This maximum width applies to the whole image block with all given columns
3. Adding columns to the image block reduces the available maximum width per image, so images might be rendered smaller than the given size as soon as the overall width of the block exceeds that maximum width.
4. By default TYPO3 does not scale images up due to poor image quality, so if you upload images that are originally smaller than the given size, they won't be scaled up but left with their original width as the maximum size.
5. If you want images of the same size properly aligned you have to upload images that are originally larger or at least identical to any of the desired sizes
6. If you insist to scale small images up you can set that in the TYPO3 configuration to override the default setting

[Prevent images from scaling up more that original size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834527/prevent-images-from-scaling-up-more-that-original-size)

https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html